# Xamarin android .axml file loading error : This item doesn't support previewing

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have installed Xamarin today & when I create a project, everything goes right but when I want to open the `.axml` file in layout folder, visual studio crashes! nothing happens & speed of the visual studio reduces the PCs performance. the only error that I get is: `This item doesn't support previewing!`

What should I do? Please help... . Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use xamarin forms previewer here?

Comment: @G.hakim: I just want to open the app design file which is .axml but I get the error!

Comment: you are trying to use the visual designer i guess?

Comment: @G.hakim: Yes! but I doesn't open...

Comment: Well xamarin visual designer has a lot of problems in it, i would suggest you use android studio to write your axml then copy that and paste it here and it will work like a charm

Comment: @G.hakim: But it was working fine in past! does repairing solve it?

Comment: No i have tried repairing and everything else and that is why i am suggesting this, i can put an answer with further detials, if you like

Comment: @G.hakim: Yes please provide an answer. Thanks for replying

Comment: @G.hakim: and something more that maybe helps in answering... I cannot even open the text editor of axml! when I click on the .axml file, Visual Studio crashes! how can I paste the script from android studio when I cannot even open the text editor?!

Comment: That crashing issue will solve with a repair, or before that try opening it with the XML editor, that would work actually or Try Source code text editor

Comment: @G.hakim: This is a screenshot: [link](https://ibb.co/iXvzoU)

Comment: @G.hakim: I have tried repairing but still it crashes!

Comment: Did you try what i suggested above?

Comment: @G.hakim: I don't have enough information about xamarin because I am new to this but I am searching for the solution about 2 days. does it relates to the version of cycle? [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556585/xamarin-visual-studio-2015-axml-designer-loading-forever?rq=1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178794/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-e-mamaghani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xamarin android designer has a lot of problems and a lot of community discussions which can be found :

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/118384/android-designer-does-not-work-well
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/125879/designer-not-loading-layout-at-all
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76851/visual-studio-2015-android-designer-not-working
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82082/android-designer-not-working-in-visual-studio-enterprise-2015
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6258/android-designer-doesnt-work-in-vs-2012
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/99268/xamarin-android-designer-not-working.html

After reading all this discussion I could not understand the actual core reason of the issue and I was actually frustrated to the point where I repaired my Visual studio, now I could see the AXML file as XML when I opened it with the designer(crash stopped). But I could still not open the designer, So what I did was as I had experience with working with the android studio and I never faced this issue, I started working on Android studio for the AXML and copy-pasted that to xamarin and it worked like a charm.

Revert in case of queries