# Xamarin designer in visual studio 2015 view only black

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, designer

I'm having problems with xamarin designer on visual studio 2015

I can add control and when deploy to device everything run normal
But designer screen shows only black
I can't see preview

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Visual studio 2015 designer has a millions bugs  check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026061/7462031

Comment: @G.hakim I was install Visual studio 2017 but nothing change

Comment: Did you uninstall the existing vs15 also what is your system configuration

Comment: Can you provide xaml code? I can test it for you

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I'm learning xamarin so the code is very simple. It is a blank android project when create new by vs2015

Comment: Try going to Tools -> Options and under Xamarin-> Android UI Designer, uncheck the option "Enable accelerated rendering". And make sure you had install latest JDK version installed. I test it in jdk_1.8.0.9, it is normal.